# Is distributing load in a balanced way between swap partitions possible?

Tags: linux, memory, performance, swap

Let's say I have two swap partitions, **`/dev/sdb and /dev/sdc`**, where **`/dev/sdb`** is 4 times faster in terms of I/O than **`/dev/sdc`**. Is it possible to configure it in such way that when the OS decides that it has 5 MB of RAM content to swap out, it directs 4 MB of it to **`/dev/sdb`** and 1 MB to **`/dev/sdc`** to provide optimal swapping speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `/dev/sdb` is 4 times faster than `/dev/sdc`, it'll be faster to fill up `/dev/sdb` first before starting on `/dev/sdc`.

Keep in mind that it's not just splitting up sequential reads and writes; there's also seek latencies, disk spin-up times, and synchronizing both disks so that one writes four parts while the other writes one.  The sequential throughput may theoretically be higher, but it's not practical.

That said, mounted [swap partitions have priorities](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/swap#Priority).  If you want to mount your two swap partitions so that `/dev/sdb` is used first and then `/dev/sdc`, consider this example:

```
sudo swapon -p 10 /dev/sdb
sudo swapon -p 5  /dev/sdc
```

In `/etc/fstab`, you would pass the `pri` option to set the priority, like so:

```
/dev/sda none swap defaults,pri=10 0 0
/dev/sdb none swap defaults,pri=5  0 0
```

---

As a practical example, you would want to do this if you were using [zram](https://askubuntu.com/q/471912/18979).  Since zram is way faster than hard drives and solid-state drives, you would like your zram swap partitions to be used first.  Here, you can see the four zram devices preferred to the slow device `/dev/zd16`:

```
deltik@node51 [~]$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/zd16                               partition   8388604 0   -1
/dev/zram0                              partition   1524800 275252  5
/dev/zram1                              partition   1524800 275400  5
/dev/zram2                              partition   1524800 276296  5
/dev/zram3                              partition   1524800 275392  5
```

(On Ubuntu, zram swap is conveniently provided by the `zram-config` package.)

Even though `/dev/zram*` are orders of magnitude faster than `/dev/zd16` sequentially, I would not want to balance the workload because `/dev/zd16` seeks way slower than `/dev/zram*` do.

Comment: See - that's what I don't understand. Looking at our simplified, theoretical case, having 5 MB it's better to load it into both partitions simultaneously, taking up 1 s than to fill up the faster partition first according to priorities given to them as it would take 1.25 s in that case. Why can't multiple devices be used in parallel, RAID-0 style? Because normally if we give both our theoretical partitions the same priority, they will be BOTH filled up with a speed of 1 MB/s, the speed of the slowest partition, why does it work like this?

Comment: Can it be configured to always squeeze top performance from such an arrangement?

Comment: @KrzysiekSetlak: You certainly can do swap on RAID-0. One way to do it is by using [md](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup#RAID-0). You can't split the I/O 4 to 1 because [striping doesn't work like that](http://superuser.com/a/822198/83694).  Nobody would bother making your desired implementation because of the shortcomings described in the second paragraph of my answer.